# Test Google Play Install Referrer API or examples

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api, install-referrer

I'm trying to use Google Play Install Referrer API to create a transparent way for the users to share my app and get benefits... but i'm having a nightmare trying to test this api

My app has a button, when user presses it gets a link which can share on other apps like:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=blablabla&amp;referrer=utm_source%3Dapp_referral%26referrer%3DUSERID`

I can actually track the `app_referral` on google dashboard, but im aiming to get `USERID` at runtime to credit the user.

I've read a ton of articles about: https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library none of them give real examples of how it will return the value, or how to test... one guy even suggested publish a test app on google play just for test

So my question is: how can i test it? if is way complicated, can you provide me some examples of how it will return?

it will return this: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=blablabla&amp;referrer=utm_source%3Dapp_referral%26referrer%3DUSERID`
or this: `referrer=utm_source%3Dapp_referral%26referrer%3DUSERID`
or this: `utm_source%3Dapp_referral%26referrer%3DUSERID`

and if there isnt any referrer at url which originated install?

please any help is appreciated